# DUAL SELECT FAILURE -1654 : ORA-01654: unable to extend index NEDINTOWNER.FD_ID_02 by 1024 in tablespace NED_INT_16M_I1

Tags: database, oracle

I am executing a script that will load the data from temp table to staging tables and from staging table to main tables. The data got loaded to the temp table and there was about 4 crore rows. But while loading from the temp table to main table i got the following error,

DUAL SELECT FAILURE -1654 : ORA-01654: unable to extend index NEDINTOWNER.FD_ID_02 by 1024 in tablespace NED_INT_16M_I1

Can anyone please help?

I tried truncating the temp table. loaded some 4/5 rows manually to the temp table and executed the part of the script where the data gets loaded from temp to main table. That also did not work..

please help on this as i am stuck up

Comment: Please show the table structure and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to Extend Index by 1024 in tablespace implies that the tablespace in which the Index `NEDINTOWNER.FD_ID_02` defined is filled.

To avoid this error, rebuild your index in a tablespace with suffucient space.